# How to generate library in a specific folder with angular-cli?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, libraries

I am using angualr7 with angular-cli and I am able to create new library with the following command.

```
E:\Coucou>ng generate library my-lib
```

By default it will add it under the project folder,but I need to generate the library under a sub folder of projects. Is there a way to do with angular-cli?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had this same issue and solved it by scoping to the subfolder.

```
ng generate library @subfolder/my-lib
```

Comment: This does work, however, one will be unable to build that target.

`ng build @subfolder/my-lib`


yields


`An unhandled exception occurred: Project '@subfolder/my-lib' does not support the 'build' target.`

Comment: @JoseOrihuela, You have to  update the path in angular.json

Comment: @FRM, thank you it works.
Do you know if it possible to create under another subfolder. someting like /folder1/folder2/my-lib?

Comment: open request on github: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11927

Answer (score 4):

you can change the default project directory to the desired directory in the angular.json

```
"newProjectRoot": "your desired directory",
```

Comment: That isn't answered my question.By the way look at the comments ;)

Answer (score -2):

Just add the path. remember are relative to where you are

```
E:\Coucou>ng generate subFolder\library my-lib
```

or

```
E:\Coucou>ng generate C:\subFolder\library my-lib
```

Comment: I do not understand why I get downvote on that question. Nobody can tel me how to solve my problem but question is not accepted by the comunity!!

Answer (score -2):

```
ng generate library my-lib --directory=folder
```